# How modify css for chat application layout especially fixed footer part

Tags: html, css

I want to create a chat application where will be the header with menu and bellow chat box with some messages and on the bottom the fixed part with input for inserting the chat message.

I've tried create the demo of this layout:

https://jsfiddle.net/6dchq2zq/2/

[image: Chat layout]

But I don't know how can I fix following issues:

1.) How calculate the height of the content where are messages and according these height show the scollbar. I've tried put the static value - for the demo.

2.) How create fixed bottom part with input which will be responsive

```css
.chat-item{
      background-color: #ffe1e1;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 50px;
    }
    
    .chat-footer{
      background-color: #dfeeff;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .chat-box{
      height: 500px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="chat-box row">
       <div class="col-md-12 chat-item">
        Test Message 1
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-md-12 chat-item">
        Test Message 2
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-md-12 chat-item">
        Test Message 3
       </div> 
       
       <div class="col-md-12 chat-item">
        Test Message 4
       </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="chat-footer">
       <div class="container">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to know the height of the content? Since you have already done such a good job on css I assume you know the benefits of using AUTO function. (no sarcasm, honest opinions)

Comment: You may want to go through the code in this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/33514655/1355315

Comment: @Sagar I don't know how do it another way only with specific height. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Already beaten by someone else on this. Plus you might want to consider adding the code by @Hipady in your **fixed footer**. 
As for the content.....if you do not have any specific reasons to know the content size then just leave it be. The chat-item will auto size as per the content. You could verify it yourself by adding some garbage text inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly added a couple lines of css

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6dchq2zq/7/

```
 .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .chat-footer {
    background-color: #dfeeff;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .chat-box {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   padding: 60px 0;
 }
```

Comment: If I try resize the window with content I can see the scrollbar overflow-x. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Jenan I removed the mistakes on my part, check the edit :)

Comment: You are right, now is great :) I think is it possible create some function for auto-scroll down? :)

Comment: @Jenan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div